# Lost a question I answered

Tags: support, specific-question

Yesterday I answered a question in a somewhat unsatisfactory way.  Today I worked out the kind of answer the questioner really wanted, but now I can't find the question.  Question was: g(x) = [f(x)-f(a)]/(x-a) x ≠ a; g(a) = f'(a).  Find g'(a).  Turns out to be f''(a)/2.  The questioner used L'Hospital's rule and asked if it could be done directly.  I now have the answer he/she was looking for but cannot find the question.

Comment: Your user profile has an "Answers" section with links to all the answers you have ever given.

Comment: I looked there but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you looked at your [meta profile](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/89003/betty-mock?tab=answers). Here are your answer:

> https://math.stackexchange.com/users/89003/betty-mock?tab=answers

Comment: Also, answers can be [sorted to put your most recent answers first](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/89003/betty-mock?tab=answers&sort=newest).